# How to show data on view

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am new in zend framework .I want to show record on view .
But I got an error to showing data  .Please help.
Thanks in advance ........

when i use foreach loop to show record

```
<?php foreach($this->fetchedData as $showData  ){ ?>

 <td><?php    echo $showData['name'];?></td>
   <td><?php  echo $showData['address'];?></td>
```

showing error as : `invalid statement used in foreach`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might be the reason :

Your $this->fetchedData may not contain data. And the foreach loop may not be able to handle it......

Try this code :

```
<?php
$data = $this->fetchedData;
if(isset($data))
{
?>

<?php foreach($this->fetchedData as $showData  ){ ?>

    <td><?php    echo $showData['name'];?></td>
    <td><?php  echo $showData['address'];?></td>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Let me know if you still face the problem.....?

Comment: you want to replace each instance of $this->fetchedData with $data just to clean it up a bit, however in essance this is correct and should satisfy the criteria. you may also want to check the controller variables $this->view->fetchedData to be sure it's supposed to be empty. could be something as simple as spelling error. We are all prone to it, I for one can't live without out them.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you should start learning the **MVC basics** of zend framwork first. There is a great tutorial series on youtube starting with [**Zend Framework 1.8 tutorial 1 MVC basics**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vhxo2oL70E).

More tutorials on [**http://www.zftutorials.com/**](http://www.zftutorials.com/).

Programmers Reference Guide [**Zend Framework & MVC Introduction**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html)

---

To solve your specific problem you should give us your code and point out the error.

---

Looping through an associative array you have to use http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

so

```
 foreach($this->fetchedData as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['names'].' and '. $value['addresses'];
 }
```

Comment: his foreach looked fine, dont need a k=>v for that

Answer (score 3):

In the controller pass your data to the view by using something like:

```
$this->view->foo = 'bar';
```

and then in the view you can access it like:

```
<?= $this->foo ?>
```